Rendering issues after Next.js deployment to Azure Web App
I'm trying to deploy a Next.js PWA to an Azure Web App using GitHub Actions. I followed this article: https://dev.to/paulriviera/deploy-nextjs-14-app-to-linux-azure-app-service-3d34. While the CI/CD pipeline runs successfully, I encounter some rendering errors when trying to access the deployed app.
In the App Service Log Stream, I can see:
2024-10-13T16:07:14.538332001Z     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
2024-10-13T16:07:14.538351203Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
2024-10-13T16:07:14.538357203Z     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
2024-10-13T16:07:14.538363004Z     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
2024-10-13T16:07:14.538368704Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-10-13T16:07:14.538374204Z   requireStack: []
2024-10-13T16:07:14.538379905Z }

Any thoughts how to fix it? What did I do wrong?
// next.config.js
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
    dest: 'public',
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    // add your own icons to src/app/manifest.ts
    // to re-generate manifest.json, you can visit https://tomitm.github.io/appmanifest/
});

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = withPWA({
    output: "standalone",
    swcMinify: true,
    reactStrictMode: true,
    eslint: {
        dirs: ['src']
    }
});


name: Deploy Next.js to Azure Web App

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  NODE_VERSION: 20
  NEXT_APP_DIR: src/FinPhlo.Web

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.NEXT_APP_DIR }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Detect package manager
        id: detect-package-manager
        run: |
          if [ -f "yarn.lock" ]; then
            echo "manager=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "runner=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          elif [ -f "package.json" ]; then
            echo "manager=npm" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=ci" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "runner=npx --no-install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "Unable to determine package manager"
            exit 1
          fi

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
          cache-dependency-path: ${{ env.NEXT_APP_DIR }}/package-lock.json

      - name: Restore cache
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: |
            ${{ env.NEXT_APP_DIR }}/.next/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('${{ env.NEXT_APP_DIR }}/package-lock.json') }}-${{ hashFiles('${{ env.NEXT_APP_DIR }}/**.[jt]s', '${{ env.NEXT_APP_DIR }}/**.[jt]sx') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('${{ env.NEXT_APP_DIR }}/package-lock.json') }}-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }}

      - name: Build with Next.js
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next build --no-lint

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip ../../web.zip ./* .next -qr

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: web-app
          path: web.zip
          retention-days: 30

  deploy-testing:
    environment:
      name: Testing
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.webapp-url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    permissions:
      id-token: write
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: web-app

      - name: Azure login
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

      - name: Deploy to Testing
        id: deployment
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: finphlo-testing-frontend-app
          package: web.zip

Terraform configuration:
module "frontend_linux_web_app" {
  source = "../../modules/web-app/linux-web-app"

  basename            = "${local.basename}-frontend"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  service_plan_id     = data.azurerm_service_plan.linux_uk_south_asp.id

  site_config = {
    always_on           = true
    minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
    ftps_state          = "Disabled"
    http2_enabled       = true
    app_command_line    = "node .next/standalone/server.js"
    application_stack = {
      node = {
        node_version = "20-lts"
      }
    }
  }

  https_only = true

  identity_type = "SystemAssigned"

  tags = var.tags
}

package.json
{
    "name": "fin-phlo",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "author": "phlo",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "turbo": "npx turbo@2.0.9",
        "build:turbo": "npm run turbo run build",
        "postbuild": "next-sitemap --config next-sitemap.config.js",
        "start": "next start",
        "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
        "check:turbo": "npm run turbo lint type-check",
        "format": "prettier --write src",
        "up-interactive": "npx npm-check-updates -i",
        "up-latest": "npx npm-check-updates -u --interactive --latest",
        "release": "cross-env HUSKY=0 standard-version",
        "push-release": "git push --follow-tags origin main",
        "prepare": "husky",
        "sanity-check": "npm run checkTs && npm run lint && npm run prettier:check",
        "checkTs": "tsc && tsc-strict",
        "eslint": "eslint --ext js,ts,tsx",
        "lint": "npm run eslint -- src",
        "lint:fix": "npm run eslint -- --fix src",
        "prettier:check": "prettier --check .",
        "prettify": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.2.3",
        "@chakra-ui/next-js": "^2.2.0",
        "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
        "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.0",
        "@types/yup": "^0.32.0",
        "framer-motion": "^11.5.4",
        "next": "^14.2.9",
        "next-auth": "^4.24.8",
        "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.53.0",
        "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
        "yup": "^1.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@commitlint/cli": "^19.4.1",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "19.4.1",
        "@commitlint/cz-commitlint": "19.4.0",
        "@types/react": "^18.3.5",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.7.0",
        "commitizen": "^4.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "eslint": "^8.57.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "^14.2.9",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-config-sznm": "^2.0.3",
        "husky": "^9.1.5",
        "lint-staged": "^15.2.10",
        "next-sitemap": "^4.2.3",
        "prettier": "^3.3.3",
        "standard-version": "^9.5.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
        "typescript": "^5.6.2",
        "typescript-strict-plugin": "^2.4.4"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=20.14.x",
        "npm": ">=9"
    },
    "packageManager": "npm@9.1.2"
}


If possible can you share your repo??

@VivekVaibhavShandilya, it is a private repo on GitHub but Azure login is just fine using Federated Credentials. It deploys the code successfully on Azure, it's just being broken - it's like it couldn't load it properly, rendering doesn't work. It says 404 Not Found in the middle although I can see the navigation menus

are you using next.js as frontend and backend both?

please share your package.json

@VivekVaibhavShandilya FE is Next.js React and BE is ASP.NET Core

@VivekVaibhavShandilya just shared the package.json in the original post

you are not deploying the node_modules folder due to which its throwing error

Initially even I got same error.
Thanks to @Azure OSS Developer Support for clear steps. This worked for me.

Updated my package.json  as below

"start": "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start",

and I did not used any startup command.

My Yml file:
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - nodewebapp15oct

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* .next -qr

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'nodewebapp15oct'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_xxxxxxxxxx }}


OUTPUT:



Thanks for the answer! Did you also have to change output to standalone in next.config.js? I've got it to a working state as well: https://pastebin.com/FLKCYvZ2, however it involves standalone output, and app_command_line = "node .next/standalone/server.js" which is something I don't like that much

@nop I did not.

That's interesting that it magically knows how to run the next.js. I'll have to try.

@nop I added my  workflow file

hmm, I was following https://github.com/zmottie/azurechatgpt/blob/b34106f1a8fec79c0c839bcfc2170c25f736bbd1/.github/workflows/open-ai-app.yml (there is infra using biceps, GitHub Actions pipeline, but the next.js is standalone build). I just tried with mine (pastebin link is in the comment above), and doesn't work without being standalone

May that be because you're unzipping the file and then are using publish profile? What's this publish-profile for?

@nop Its for authentication. In your workflow file you are using client id, tenant id, subscription.. i am using publish profile.. And I am unzipping file before deployment.. even if i use release.zip in package it will work same.

Thanks, it makes sense now. https://pastebin.com/vmDDG6iv - this is my current configuration that works but images from the public folder are missing. Is there I could see the file system of the App Service so I see what gets copied and what's missing?

I was following https://github.com/cu-cit-cloud-team/aoai-gpt-chat-demo/blob/9a94776d2e810fa6088c48b54933894dae9104c9/.github/workflows/build-and-deploy.yml but they don't do anything specific to the public folder, I wonder what the difference is

@nop You can check your files in kudu console. https://your-webappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui for linux. Open file manager go to site->wwwroot. Inside wwwroot folder you will see your all deployed files..

Thanks, I just did that. I can see the files in the public folder: https://i.imgur.com/7Fnn8PM.png. However, I see a lot of 404s in the .next/static folder: https://i.imgur.com/yUluEUl.png. https://pastebin.com/uYpXk6ip this is the current pipeline code
